# Calculating Decile Intervals in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a relatively simple (hopefully) Snowflake SQL question which I have been unable to answer for myself online. For the sake of simplicity, let's just say I have one simple table with an ID column and a value column.

```
   Id |   Value
-------------------
  A   |  100 | 
  B   |  245 | 
  C   |  80  | 
  D   |  370 | 
  E   |  65  |
```

I would like to calculate the decile buckets for the value column. So far, I have only found commands which will add a decile rank as an additional column, ranking each value between 0-9. However this is not quite what I need. I am more interested in seeing what these deciles actually are. For instance, for decile 0, I would like to know the interval for which that spans, let's say something that looks like [0,99) for instance. Is anyone aware of how to generate this data? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select tile, min(value), max(value)
from (select t.*, ntile(10) over (order by value) as tile
      from t
     ) t
group by tile
order by tile;
```

Note that `ntile()` may not handle ties the way you expect.  But the point is that if you can get the logic in an additional column, then aggregation gets the ranges you want.